# Java Client to receive SilverLight push data

Tags: java, c#

is there any APIs available to write java code/client which receives SilverLight server's Push data or listening Silverlight server's Socket?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Silverlight technology is similar to JavaFX in Java, but it is not necessary to use JavaFX. In your case, you may be use [Java API for WebSocket (JSR 356)](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr356/index.html)